# How can I set condition in Class property?

Tags: typescript

I want to set

private numberOfWheels: number; // bigger than -1

how can I set inside of the class ?

```
class Vehicle {
  private numberOfWheels: number; // bigger than -1
  public wheels: Wheel[];
  private fuel: number;

  constructor(numberOfWheels: number, wheels: Wheel[], fuel: number) {
    this.numberOfWheels = numberOfWheels
    this.wheels = wheels;
    this.fuel = fuel;
  }
  getNumberOfWheels(): number { return this.numberOfWheels; }

  getFuel(): number {return this.fuel; }
}
```

Comment: typescript currently does not have a way to limit the range of numbers.

Comment: than I should set condition outside of the class ?

Comment: Relevant [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480)

Comment: @YankeeCki you can write an if statement in your constructor